# 这样一来还打个屁啊- What does this mean?

Tags: translation

I'm looking for clarification as to what 这样一来还打个屁啊 means.
I've already done a rough translation and I think it means: thus if there is bullshit.
But it doesn't make total sense to me in the full context.

Full Context: 呵呵，照你们这么说，那么敌人随随便便给出一些谣言，就吓得我们不敢入侵，这样一来还打个屁啊，还不如回去好了。

My understanding: Oh, according to you guys, if the enemy casually spread some rumors to scare us so we don't dare to invade, thus if there is still bullshit, it is better to go retreat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

这样一来还打个屁啊 is a more intense version of 这样一来还打个啥啊, meaning ***if things go like that (what the author had mentioned "那么敌人随随便便给出一些谣言，就吓得我们不敢入侵"), then it's pointless to fight***. He goes on with 还不如回去好了(we'd rather go back).

这样一来还打个屁啊 denotes the sense of ***hopeless to win so no need to fight*** given the fact that aforementioned.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!